# View Cached Google Map in Open Data Kit's Collect Application

Tags: google-maps, cache, open-data-kit

I am using Open Data Kit to collect data on an Android tablet.  The ODK form was built using the ODK Build application on-line.  The Build application allows the user to record a latitude and longitude and view the current GNSS location on a Google Map background-this works great if I have a wifi connection.  Since my tablet does not have a cellular connection I have cached the Google Maps tiles on to the tablet.  I can view the tiles when there is no wifi connection in the Google Maps app so I know the caching works.  I cannot view the cached map tiles while collecting data in the field while using the ODK Collect app without wifi.
  Since these Android devices store the last know location it might record/report an invalid location given GNSS availability. I would like to see the current location I am recording on a map to ensure that I am in the correct location.

Is there some way to see the cached map tiles in the ODK Collect app on the tablet?